# How to add button in a flexigrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexigrid

good day i have a flex grid but it doesnt work when i add buttons here is my code

html:

```
        $("#flex1").flexigrid
        (
        {
        url: 'post.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        colModel : [
            {display: 'OR#', name : 'OR', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: 'FIRST NAME', name : 'firstname', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'LAST NAME', name : 'lastname', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'DATE', name : 'date', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'PARTICULARS', name : 'particulars', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'LEFT'},
            {display: 'AMOUNTS', name : 'amounts', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'LEFT',},
            {display: 'ACTIONS', name : 'actions', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'LEFT',},
            ],

        searchitems : [
            {display: 'or#', name : 'or'},
            {display: 'Last name', name : 'lastname',},
            {display: 'First name', name : 'firstname', isdefault: true},
            ],


        sortname: "iso",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        useRp: true,
        rp: 15,
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        width: 'auto',
        onSubmit: addFormData,
        height: 200
        }

        );
```

when i try to add this codes it doesnt display anything.

```
            buttons : [
            {name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : test},
            {name: 'Delete', bclass: 'delete', onpress : test},
            {separator: true}
            ],
```

thanks for the help

Comment: whether the onpress test() method is declared? can you setup a jsfiddle to look into that

Comment: Please check your tags, [flexgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/flexgrid/info) is not [flexigrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/flexigrid/info). You might not be able to target correct users

Comment: the same issue for me